# Plot 4D plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I know that I am beating a dead horse, but I could not find a proper answer.

I want to make a plot from large data:

```
X-Coord   Y-Coord   Z-Coord   Value
20'000 rows
```

when I invoke

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
```

I get an error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new 1.py", line 17, in <module>
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)  # <-- returns a 2D grid from initial 1D arrays
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4698, in meshgrid
    output = [x.copy() for x in output]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4698, in <listcomp>
    output = [x.copy() for x in output]
MemoryError
```

Actually I simply want to have a 3D surface from X Y Z coordinates and to plot value from column Value in this coordinate. Give me please a suggestion

UPD:
example of data

```
          X                       Y                       Z                     Value
-3.6296815834229800E+13 9.0179395964544800E+13  4.3243022996875400E+13  2.3293827867020395e-03
-3.6546185417114900E+13 8.9339697982272400E+13  4.3845054348437700E+13  2.2153085734286245e-03
-3.6546185417114900E+13 9.2024057357272400E+13  4.3845054348437700E+13  2.6335681277863542e-03
-3.6795554999999900E+13 8.8500000000000000E+13  4.4447085699999900E+13  2.2448110225069475e-03
-3.6795554999999900E+13 9.1184359374999900E+13  4.4447085699999900E+13  2.3661800082893664e-03
-3.6795554999999900E+13 9.3868718749999900E+13  4.4447085699999900E+13  3.1766708204588683e-03
-3.6296815834229800E+13 9.0179395964544800E+13  4.3243022996875400E+13  2.3293827867020395e-03
-3.6546185417114900E+13 9.2024057357272400E+13  4.3845054348437700E+13  2.6335681277863542e-03
-3.6337452147547400E+13 9.0857342861310100E+13  4.3341127722985300E+13  2.4227047423936087e-03
-3.6795554999999900E+13 9.3868718749999900E+13  4.4447085699999900E+13  3.1766708204588683e-03
-3.6586821730432500E+13 9.2702004254037600E+13  4.3943159074547600E+13  2.8272105071883709e-03
-3.6378088460865000E+13 9.1535289758075300E+13  4.3439232449095200E+13  2.5588155147357474e-03
-3.6378088460865000E+13 9.1535289758075300E+13  4.3439232449095200E+13  2.6341575316456271e-03
-3.6586821730432500E+13 9.2702004254037600E+13  4.3943159074547600E+13  2.8628186103490019e-03
-3.6491956423152800E+13 9.3434980585604900E+13  4.3714133992590100E+13  3.2129310022084552e-03
-3.6795554999999900E+13 9.3868718749999900E+13  4.4447085699999900E+13  3.1710978217960057e-03
-3.6700689692720300E+13 9.4601695081567300E+13  4.4218060618042400E+13  3.5478526100425675e-03
-3.6605824385440600E+13 9.5334671413134600E+13  4.3989035536084900E+13  3.9315260648101454e-03
-3.6196152400000000E+13 8.8500000000000000E+13  4.3000000000000000E+13  5.1978166985800038e-03
-3.6495853699999900E+13 8.8500000000000000E+13  4.3723542849999900E+13  4.8689291409766524e-03
```

UPD2:
Thanks for good solution from @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

finally to speed up data processing during rotation of scatter I reduced the arrays and used another backend. Also added a colorbar for results.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('svg')

x,y,z,v = np.loadtxt("datafile.txt", skiprows=2, unpack=True)
if len(x) > 400000:
  x = x[::50] 
  y = y[::50] 
  z = z[::50]
  v = v[::50] 
elif len(x) > 200000:
  x = x[::20] 
  y = y[::20] 
  z = z[::20]
  v = v[::20] 
elif len(x) > 100000:
  x = x[::10] 
  y = y[::10] 
  z = z[::10]
  v = v[::10]   

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


ax.scatter(x,y,z,c=v, s=10, cmap=cm.rainbow)

m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.rainbow)

m.set_array(v)
cbar = plt.colorbar(m)

plt.show()
```

Comment: You are creating two arrays with 20000 * 20000 elements each, i.e. 800 Million entries in total. This would take ~3 GB memory if they were integers, or ~6 GB memory if they are floats. It may be that your memory is not large enough to hold them. However, it is not clear what those columns contain as data and why you use `meshgrid` here. Use a small example with some 20 rows first, but make that reproducible to get help here, see [mcve].

Comment: I added an example of my data. Regarding RAM I have 64Gb on my machine

Comment: Since the coordinates in the table seem rather random, `meshgrid` will not help at all. The two options you have: interpolate on a regular grid, or use a triangulation.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, but is there any possibility simply to create a point (XYZ) and than set a value to this point from 4th column ? after that color all points and in best case connect nearest points or smth like this to the surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a scatter plot to plot the points with color according to the last column of the table; then a `plot_trisurf` may be used to get the idea of a surface accross.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y,z,v = np.loadtxt("datafile.txt", skiprows=1, unpack=True)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(x,y,z, edgecolor="gray", color="None")
ax.scatter(x,y,z,c=v, s=100)
```

[image]